# Probability Question - Flip until 3 heads, will a 5th flip occur?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

You keep flipping a coin until you have a total of 3 heads. What's the probability a 5th flip will occur?

My logic:
this will be $1 - \text{Pr}(3 \text{heads within 4 flips})$

and
$$
\text{Pr}(\text{3 heads within 4 flips}) = \binom{4}{3}/16 = 1/4
$$

answer is therefore 3/4.

However, I feel this is wrong....any comments/suggestions?

Comment: @jcneek Your comment is incorrect.  Please see my answer below to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if the first three flips are heads?  Then you stop right away.  So the event you actually need to consider is getting 3 heads in 4 **or fewer** flips.  This has probability $1/8 + 3/16 = 5/16$, and the desired complementary probability is $11/16$, not $3/4$.

Another way to think about it is like this.  Flip the coin four times, no matter what the outcome.  This leads to $2^4 = 16$ possible sequences of heads and tails, each of which is equally likely to occur (if the coin is fair).  Then among these outcomes, which ones have **at least** $3$ heads?  We must have the "at least" condition because the outcome where all four flips were heads still causes you to stop before the fifth coin toss as you had already gotten three heads in the first three flips.  So the outcomes where you stop within 4 flips are
$$(H,H,H,H), \\ (H,H,H,T), \\ (H,H,T,H), \\ (H,T,H,H), \\ (T,H,H,H),$$ and there are clearly five of these.
Finally, we can also compute this using a negative binomial distribution.  $X$ counts the number of flips needed to obtain $r = 3$ heads, where $p = 1/2$ is the probability of any single flip being heads.  Then $X$ has a negative binomial distribution with PMF
$$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{x-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^{x-r}, \quad x \in \{r, r+1, r+2, \ldots \}.$$
The desired probability is $$\Pr[X \ge 5] = 1 - \Pr[3 \le X \le 4] = 1 - \sum_{x=3}^4 (x-1)(x-2) (1/2)^{x+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{8} - \frac{3}{16}.$$